# Cmake build error for c++

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I want to build the bayes optimization program error is

```
The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
CMake Error: Generator: execution of make failed. Make command was: "C:\MinGW\bin" "cmTryCompileExec2576605559/fast"
Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61 (message):
```

The C compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
          program.

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: C:/Code-Lite-Test/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
Run Build Command:"C:\MinGW\bin" "cmTryCompileExec2576605559/fast"
Access is denied
Generator: execution of make failed.  Make command was: "C:\MinGW\bin"
"cmTryCompileExec2576605559/fast"
CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
```

I have downloaded source from url https://bitbucket.org/rmcantin/bayesopt/ and i have downloaded the MinGW compiler for Windows when I try to build the program the error is:

Please help me on this I have also deleted the old cache when I try to build the bayes optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to compile a simple C++ program first without CMake. E.g. store a simple `main.cpp` somewhere in your user directory `C:\Users\<yourname>\Temp` directory with following content:

```
int main() 
{
   return 0;
}
```

Now open CMD window in your `C:\Users\<yourname>\Temp` directory and run:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe main.cpp -o testprog
```

If an error popup appears that is saying something about a missing .dll, run following command in your CMD window and try to compile again:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\MinGW\bin
```

If you had to run the last command, add the C:\MinGW\bin path permanently. After all it should be possible to run `CMake` with MinGW as compiler.

Comment: When i try that i got the error like this
C:\>gcc.exe main.cpp -o testprog
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/
bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file testprog.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with your permissions. Maybe you try it in a directory in your user directory e.g. C:\Users\yourname\temp

Comment: I have moved Mingw to uesr directory same error has shown.

Comment: Please don't move MinGW to another directory. I'll change my answer that it uses the user's directory.

Comment: k sir,i have moved to mingw to F:\SOFTWARE\other2\MinGW\bin than also i gives same error.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your MinGW compiler for Windows is able to build a simple program **without** CMake, for example: [Hello World](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw_for_first_time_users_howto)

When it works, clean your cache and try again.