# Catch2 test don't work when building application with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, catch2

I'm trying to test my program by using Catch2 tests and build the application using CMake. The program works and the application gets build when the Catch2 tests are not implemented.
Once I implemented the Catch2 tests, the application won't build anymore. I included `#define CONFIG_CATCH_MAIN` and `#include "catch.hpp"` into main.cpp.

But I always get something like this when I try to build the application with the tests included:

CMakeFiles\intent_recognition.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x43d): undefined reference to `Catch::StringRef::StringRef(char const*)' CMakeFiles\intent_recognition.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj):main.cpp:(.text+0x4b9): undefined reference to` Catch::AssertionHandler::AssertionHandler(Catch::StringRef const&, Catch::SourceLineInfo const&, Catch::StringRef, Catch::ResultDisposition::Flags)'

I don't know what's going...

My main.cpp file looks like this:

```
#define CONFIG_CATCH_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Intent.h"

std::string func (std::string input)
{
    std::cout << input << std::endl;

    Intent IntentObj = Intent(input);       // create Intent Object with input

    IntentObj.analyze();

    return IntentObj.result();
}

TEST_CASE("Get Weather", "[func]")
{
    REQUIRE( func("What is the weather like today?") == "Intent: Get Weather" );
    REQUIRE( func("Tell me what the weather is like.") == "Intent: Get Weather") ;
    REQUIRE( func("I want to know the weather for tomorrow") == "Intent: Get Weather" );
    REQUIRE( func("Can you tell me the weather for Wednesday?") == "Intent: Get Weather") ;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20.2)

project(intent_recognition)

add_executable(intent_recognition main.cpp)
```

Comment: how dd you use cach2 in `CMakeLists.txt`? it [works for me](https://github.com/MarekR22/class_of_in_cpp/blob/main/test/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: Well I don't know the test framework, but those errors seem to be linker errors. Do you have the library implementing those functions linked properly to the test executable?
Please put your CMakeLists.txt into your question!

Comment: So problem is invalid `CMakeLists.txt` see example I've provided.

Answer (score 1):

Having a quick look at the [Catch2 tutorial](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/cmake-integration.md#cmake-target) you are at least missing the specification of the Catch2 library to link.
The tutorial states that you are at least need to have this code which your file above seems to miss:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
add_executable(tests test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(tests PRIVATE Catch2::Catch2)
```

The `target_link_libraries...` is missing in your example. That's probably why you are getting those linker errors.
The `find_package` will introduce the library under the name `Catch2::Catch2` which you can then link to your test executable.
If the `find_package command` is not working in your setup, you may need to check how you did install Catch2.

Comment: Yep, this is same as example I've provided in comment (before `CMakeLists.txt` was shown).

Comment: It still won't work for me. When I try to build it with CMake on the command line, it says

By not providing "FindCatch2.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Catch2", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Catch2" with any
  of the following names:

    Catch2Config.cmake
    catch2-config.cmake"

I don't know where to get those files. I thought that the header file from Catch2 would be enough to make the tests work ...

Comment: For `find_package` to work you need to [install](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/issues/1383) Catch2 first. If you don't want to do that you can use `FetchContent` as described [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/devel/docs/cmake-integration.md).

Comment: I tried to install Catch2 but it doesn't work. I cloned the repo and input the commands but it said "The C++ Compiler MinGW/bin/g++.exe is not able to compile a simple test program.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65444608/mingw-bin-gcc-exe-is-not-able-to-compile-a-simple-test-program) question for the g++ problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to use Catch2 as a header only library. The problem may be because you are including [include/catch.hpp](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/tree/v2.13.6/include) instead of [single_include/catch2/catch.hpp](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/tree/v2.13.6/single_include/catch2).

Comment: I included the header "single_include/catch2/catch.hpp" but it still doesn't work

Comment: How are you consuming Catch2? It's not clear from the question. Did you clone the repo and simply set the include path to `single_include/catch2`?

Comment: I just downloaded the header file and included it into my main.cpp

Comment: And the error you're getting in this case is the same as the one in your original question?

Comment: Then maybe opening an issue on the Catch repository is the better option.